# Assigned filetype for backups not applying

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, backup, maintenance-plans

I am working to migrate backups over to a new storage point. I figured the easiest thing to do was to duplicate the configuration over from the existing Maintenance Plan to a new one, just in case something goes wrong with the new backup point in the short term.

I copied over the existing configuration and ran the Maintenance Plan to test, but ran into an issue where one of the DBs didn't append the `.bak` filetype. Instead, it went with nothing or `.b` as the filetype.

The code within the T-SQL on the new backup Maintenance Plan matches the original, so I am unsure why it's acting like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more investigation and review, we found that the filename size was too long and was cutting off the tail end of the name. It's very likely the issue has been going on for some time, but was never noticed until the changeover.